# Can I load XHTML file in webview in store app?

Tags: c#, windows-8, webview, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

**Right now I am loading HTML file in webview by placing into the Assets folder(it's working fine).. 
if I try do like that for XHTML file it is displaying as blank in webview.**

Question: Can I load XHTML file in webview in store app from local drive?

Any help needed...

Comment: Working for me, I tried this [sample XHTML](http://fgamedia.org/faculty/rdcormia/COIN74A/xhtmlExamples/SampleXhtml.html)

Comment: @Xyroid  What's your link. I didn't get anything. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: I tried this, it worked for me. `ie` is instance of WebView `ie.Navigate(new Uri("http://fgamedia.org/faculty/rdcormia/COIN74A/xhtmlExamples/SampleXhtml.html"));`

Comment: @Xyroid 
I want top load from my **local folder not using any URL**.
For HTML I am using this
`webview1.Source = new Uri("ms-appx-web:///assets/Copy of nav.html");`
I want it for XHTML.
_Please read my question once again_

Waiting for your reply...

Comment: It is working for me, I saved that SampleXhtml.html‌, can you please give me the source of that HTML ? Post it on http://pastebin.com

Comment: @Xyroid My intention is to load XHTML from local drive..
please save it with XHTML extention & try to load in webview.
I pasted my sample XHTML content in [http://pastebin.com/heN80wyS ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the problem is XHTML document does not become part of project as its build action is set to None. You have to include it. To do follow this steps.

1. Right click on that XHTML document & click on property.
2. Open combo box of property "Build Action"
3. It has default "None", change it to "Content"
4. That's it. Test and reply back. If it works, don't forget to mark it as answer.

**UPDATE 1**

Load XHTML from assets

`MyWebView.Source = new Uri("ms-appx-web:///Assets/test.xhtml");`

Load XHTML from local folder :

```
var XHTML = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("test.xhtml");
MyWebView.NavigateToString(await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(XHTML));
```

Comment: It's working fine..
I want to load xhtml file from my local folder without pasting into Assets folder. My next step is that one only. How can I change every 
file. 
 


I want to know.

Comment: I want to do **load XHTML file with intention of coding**, &
_what's reason for changing property of Build._

Comment: Content Build property will include that file in app package.

Comment: @Xyriod, When I try to load in Local folder, I am not getting success; 
Before loading XHTML file  I am defining my folder by 
`StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;`
when I am using "awiat" it is getting error.
Can you please verify it.

Comment: Have you used `async` keyword in method/event signature ? If you are loading XHTML from event then use `async void` as return type otherwise `async Task<T>`, where `T` is return type class if applicable.

Comment: **Thank you very much**. It's working Fine; I am new to C# Concepts like async & await. The XHTML is loading in Webview from package folder. If there is any inner link in webview means it is working, But I want **load using link of anchor tag also which will redirect to another page placed in same folder**. Any suggestion or Any link form wed also appreciated,

Comment: You better ask new question in detail, it is not good to discuss here.